# ¿Cómo cambiar la forma de un dataframe sin usar arrays, con Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Tengo un dataframe, por ejemplo el siguiente:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'No':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]})
```

quiero cambiar la forma del data frame de la siguiente forma:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'1': [1, 2, 3],
               '2': [4, 5, 6],
               '3': [7, 8, 9]})
```

ando un poco perdida porque he visto muchas funciones que sirven para cambiar la forma de los dataframe pero no veo claramente cuál sería la adecuada.

Ojo: me gustaría usar herramientas propias de pandas, porque se puede convertir a numpy array y después hacer un reshape, pero quisiera no estar cambiando de pandas a numpy.

Comment: Con que criterio deben agruparse los datos? Debe haber una nueva columna cada 3 elementos?

Comment: Exacto, cada cierto número de elementos. En el caso del ejemplo, sí, cada 3 elementos.

Comment: Bien. Entonces iba por buen camino! Pregunta. Depende del largo del Dataframe el numero de elementos? O simplemente es constante?

Comment: No necesariamente. Quizás sólo en el caso de que no desees espacios vacíos. Es decir si el modulo del largo de la serie con respecto al numero de elementos por columna es diferente de cero, habría que cortar la serie antes, para no incluir el residuo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se si es el mejor, pero se me ocurre el siguiente modo:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'No':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]})

n = 3
new_df = pd.DataFrame(dict(enumerate(df["No"].iloc[i:i+n].values for i in range(0,df.shape[0],n))))

print(new_df)
```

Que produce

```
   0  1  2
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9
```

El plan es recorrer un rango que va de 0 al alto del dataframe con saltos de n. En este caso sería 0, 3, 6. De ahí tomamos un pedazo que va de i a i + n del dataframe. Es equivalente a ponerse a hacer `df["No"].iloc[0:3], df["No"].iloc[3:6] ... df["No"].iloc[i:i + n]`

Finalmente accedemos al atributo values de la serie resultante, que si bien es un array numpy, no necesitas usar (externamente) funciones de numpy.

Usamos enumerate para convertir el generador de arrays (vease [comprensiones de listas y otras colecciones](https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/comprension-de-listas-y-otras-colecciones/)) en un iterador que va devolviendo tuplas de esta forma `(0, array0), (1, array1), ...`
Finalmente, convertimos eso en un diccionario (recién aqui el iterador comienza a ser consumido y los dataframes se generan) compatible con el constructor del dataframe.

Esto termina siendo un diccionario así:

```
{0:[1,2,3], 1:[4,5,6], ...}
```